# Rename a new file when there in file with the same name without limited name

Tags: python

I wrote a code to create a text file and write something. But when code start again it overwrite a file and delete old text. I know append method but I want to save new text in the new file. I import pathlib but it's not good for many rename:

```
from pathlib import path

ExampleName = path(./example.txt)
if ExampleName.exist():
   ExampleName = path(./example2.txt)

with open(example_name, mode= 'w') as t_file:
    t_file.write('blah blah blah')
    t_file.close()
```

also I use time module. Its better than pathlib but I want to create file from 1 to up not a random extream!!! number:

```
import time

AppendName = str(time.time())

with open(f'./example{AppendName}.txt', mode='w') as t_file:
    t_file.write('blah blah blah')
    t_file.close()
```

In this case I cant recognize what text file is older than another file.

Comment: You've mentioned using time module.
Have you tried appending current timestamp (https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) to your file name?

Comment: actually I know this but its makes name too long. I looking for better approach. But if I wouldn't find i use of this.

Comment: You can try using datetime (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). You could do something like ```currentDateTime = datetime.now()```, and then grab whatever your need from it. Example would be ```currentDateTime.hour()```.

Answer (score 0):

Might not what you want to reach, try like that:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path


def file_checker(file):
    if Path(file).exists():
        with open(file, 'r') as file1, open(f'{file}-{datetime.now()}', 'a') as file2:
            file2.write(file1.read())
            file2.write('\nblah blah blah')


file_checker('example.txt')
```

or like that with shutil:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def file_checker(file):
    if Path(file).exists():
        new_file_name = f"{file}-{datetime.now()}"
        shutil.copyfile(file, new_file_name)
        with open(new_file_name, 'a') as new_file:
            new_file.write('\nblah blah blah')
    else:
        with open(file, 'w') as file1:
            file1.write('blah blah blah')


file_checker('example.txt')
```